# how to import specific rows into r?

Tags: r

I am new to R and try to clean my data by using it.
for the first and second phases, I mark some of my rows by `*` and `**` and import them to R for cleaning and now I want to import the rest of the rows (rows that are not marked by `*` and `**`) for cleaning but I don't know how to specify the.

Comment: you can import all rows and then choose the ones you want using bracket notation or a `dplyr::filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "import specific rows" we assume that this means that you need to read it from a file.  Now assuming the input file `BOD_na.csv` generated reproducibly in the Note at the end read it specifying a comment character of `*` and `fill=TRUE` to fill in unspecified fields (due to the star comment) with NA.  Then all we need to do is remove the lines with NA which can be done using `na.omit`.   As the `str` output shows this correctly reads numeric columns with stars as numeric whereas if we read them in the normal manner and then removed the stars such columns would erroneously be read as character.  No packages are used.

```
# get lines not having a star
BOD_0 <- "BOD_na.csv" |>
  read.csv(comment.char = "*", fill = TRUE) |>
  na.omit()

BOD_0
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3
## 3    4   16.0
## 4    5   15.6
## 5    7   19.8

str(BOD_0)
## 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ Time  : int  1 4 5 7
##  $ demand: num  8.3 16 15.6 19.8
##  - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int 2
##   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "2"
```

### Note

```
# create test file
BOD_na <- BOD
BOD_na[2,1] <- BOD_na[3,2] <- "*"
write.csv(BOD_na, "BOD_na.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
rm(BOD_na)

read.csv("BOD_na.csv")
##   Time demand
## 1    1    8.3
## 2    *   10.3
## 3    3      *
## 4    4     16
## 5    5   15.6
## 6    7   19.8
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by @TTS, the dplyr::filter function would do the job. I would also import the file in R and then sort out the data that are not needed.
Using a reproducible example is easier, so let's start from these data:

```
a=c("Car","Boat","Bus","Bike")
b=c(50,10,71,103)
c=c(0,0,"**",0)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c)
> df
     a   b  c
1  Car  50  0
2 Boat  10  0
3  Bus  71 **
4 Bike 103  0
```

Now we can exclude the rows where `c` is `**`:

```
df2 <- df %>% filter(!c=="**")
> df2
     a   b c
1  Car  50 0
2 Boat  10 0
3 Bike 103 0
```